# NHibernate and EF, execute query outside context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nhibernate

I know this is a crazy thing to ask.. but Ill give it a shot :)
Is there anyway to build up your linq/query and then later on be able to build even more on it and then execute it.. for instance like this:

```
        public void Test()
    {
        var k = TestRepo();
        k = k.Where(e => e.SomeColumn == someValue);

        rp.DataSource = k.Select(t => t.Id);
        rp.DataBind();
    }


    public IEnumerable<ApplicationEntity> TestRepo()
    {
        using (var x = new MyEntityContext())
        {
            return from q in x.MyColumn
                   select q;
        }
    }
```

If im not misstaken this whould never work :)... but whouldnt it be just great if you first could "build" the basics of the query and then extend it somemore and then once its finaly ready actually execute it and get the result..
So is there anyway to do this as in the example above with EF or NHibernate.. or both of em?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the spelling.. went kind of fast there :/

Comment: you can edit the text to repair those spelling errors ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is *not* to dispose the `MyEntityContext`. For instance, you can cache it for the lifetime of a request and dispose it at the end of an request. This might look like this:

```
public static class ContextFactory
{
private static bool disposeRegistered = false;

public static MyEntityContext GetContext()
{
    RegisterDispose();

    var instance = (MyEntityContext)HttpContext.Current
        .Items["MyEntityContext"];

    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new MyEntityContext();

        HttpContext.Current.Items["MyEntityContext"] =
            instance;
    }

    return instance;    
}

private static void RegisterDispose()
{
    if (disposeRegistered)
        return;

    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance
       .EndRequest += (s,e) =>
    {
        var instance = HttpContext.Current
            .Items["MyEntityContext"] as IDisposable;

        if (instance != null)
        {
            instance.Dispose();
        }
    };

    this.disposeRegistered = true;
}
}
```

The `TestRepo` method than looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> TestRepo()
{
    var x = ContextFactory.GetContext()

    return 
        from employee in x.Employees
        where employee.Salary > 1000
        select employee;
}
```

Note how the `TestRepo` now returns `IQueryable`. This allows other methods to change the query and only when you start iterating it, the query will get sent to the database.

NOTE: Instead of taking a dependency on a static `ContextFactory` class, you could also inject an `MyEntityContext` into types that wish to use it. You can use this by using a technique called Dependency Injection.

Comment: What whould happen if I whould return an IEnumerable from the TestRepo?.. whould this still work but with the difference that all things that aint set as "Include" whouldnt exist for the returned object?..such as different tables an references..

Comment: Returning an `IEnumerable` would still work, but if you add filters (`where`) and transformations (`select`, `group by` etc) they are executed in memory, instead of being translated to SQL. In other words, your initial query is executed on the database which could lead to returning too many records that you filter out locally, which could lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression it *would* work, *if* your return type from `TestRepo()` was set instead as `IQueryable<ApplicationEntity>`.  I would like it demonstrated otherwise :-/  Seems like I've done something like that before.

Comment: You know what, Steven's comment is probably more valid.  (I was wondering why a type cast should do anything!)

Comment: The *other* thing I did was serialize my query it to objects in memory via .ToList()   That way, you can extend your expressions, but you're basically doing LINQ To Objects at that point.